# 120 days in Beta - We're fighting it

Tags: discussion

[image]

and together with the [30-days](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/30-dias-in-beta-we-need-more-questions) , [60-days](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/60-days-in-beta-battle-cry) and [90-days](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/90-days-in-beta-stable-or-stagnant) numbers

\begin{array}{| r | r |}
  \hline 
\hline                       
  \text {Metric} & \text {30 B-days} & \text{60 B-days} & \text{90 B-days} & \text{120 B-days}\\
  \hline                      
\text {Q per day} & 5.1 & 5.3 & 5.4 & 4.5\\
\text{% answered} & \text {85%} & \text {84%} & \text {80%} & \text {79%}\\
\text{avid users | %} & 38 | \text {8%} & 48 |\text {6.6%} & 54 | \text {5.5%} & 58 | \text {4.8%}\\
\text {total users} & 473 & 730 & 981 & 1210\\
\text {Engaged users %(*)} & N/A & 33\text{%} & 34\text{%} & 37\text{%}\\
\text {answer ratio} & 1.9 & 1.8 & 1.8 & 1.7\\
\text {Visits/day} & 238 & 202 & 192 & 225\\
  \hline  
\end{array}

**(*)**"Engaged Users" are those that do *not* have reputation $1$ or $101$, i.e. those that had at count day performed some reputation-affecting activity on the site (I count out also the $101$'s because the $100$ points are SE-registration bonus if they are active on other sites). I decided to show "engaged" rather than "unengaged" users, since all other metrics in the table have the association "larger value = better".

**COMMENTARY**

Officially, previously we had two "Okay"s, but **we lost the "Q per day"** one, since it fell below the $5$-threshold.

**The "% answered" metric does not really frighten me** - in my opinion we will experience the same issues as [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/): an abnormally high (compared to other SE sites) percentage of unanswered questions, because Economics questions are so diverse and complex.

The **continuing slowing growth** (ah, what an *economistic* phrase!), and continuing falling percentage over Total, of the **"Avid Users"** metric really worries me. We have *only* 58 people with +$200$ reputation here, which *has fell* to **just $4,8$% of total registered users**. That's low, the "150 Avid Users" target is sensible and important. But if exponential growth does not set in (to be followed by concavity of course, but we need the intermediate convexity), at that rate it will take more than a year to reach 150 Avid Users...

> **So, what does it take to be "persuaded" to become an Avid User in Economics. SE?** (you might want to post an answer on the matter, especially those of you who are not persuaded yet)

**"Total Users"** increase is impressively steady (from a statistical point of view) at $7-8$ new registrations daily.

The **first good news** is that my **"Engaged Users"** metric increased a visible 3 percentage points.

The **"Answer Ratio"** slightly backed down... it is interesting that in a Social discipline where apparently scholars disagree all the time, we don't see a shower of disagreeing answers per question...does it have to do with the nature of the questions?

The **second good news** here is that **"Visits per Day"** bounced back up (I remind that this is the *median* not the *average*).

**So, we're fighting it.**

Comment: I keep posting links to interesting questions on Facebook, but people just comment /answer them there, instead of here.

Comment: IMO This site is going pretty well. It's an SE with a good foundation, and I think it just needs to see some solid growth.