# 150 days in Beta - Is it picking up speed?

Tags: discussion

[image]

and together with the [60-days](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/60-days-in-beta-battle-cry), [90-days](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1279/90-days-in-beta-stable-or-stagnant) and [120-days](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/120-days-in-beta-were-fighting-it) numbers

\begin{array}{| r | r |}
  \hline 
\hline                       
  \text {Metric} & \text{60 B-days} & \text{90 B-days} & \text{120 B-days} & \text{150 B-days}\\
  \hline                      
\text {Q per day}  & 5.3 & 5.4 & 4.5 & 7.4\\
\text{% answered}  & \text {84%} & \text {80%} & \text {79%} & \text {80%}\\
\text{avid users | %} & 48 |\text {6.6%} & 54 | \text {5.5%} & 58 | \text {4.8%} & 63 | \text {4.3%}\\
\text {total users} & 730 & 981 & 1210 & 1455\\
\text {Engaged users %(*)} & 33\text{%} & 34\text{%} & 37\text{%} & 37\text{%}\\
\text {answer ratio}  & 1.8 & 1.8 & 1.7 & 1.7\\
\text {Visits/day (median)}  & 202 & 192 & 225 & 308\\
  \hline  
\end{array}

**(*)**"**Engaged Users**" are those that do *not* have reputation $1$ or $101$, i.e. those that had at count day performed some reputation-affecting activity on the site (I count out also the $101$'s because the $100$ points are SE-registration bonus if they are active on other sites). I decided to show "engaged" rather than "unengaged" users, since all other metrics in the table have the association "larger value = better".

(**P.S.** The **30-days** numbers can be found [here](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/30-dias-in-beta-we-need-more-questions))

**COMMENTARY**

For the first time in these 150 days the numbers gave me the impression that **it is picking up speed.**

Q's/day and visits per day have visibly increased while the rate of new registrations per day is unbelievably constant during all these 5-month period (7-9 new accounts per day, month per month). **But this means that already registered users are becoming returning customers at a higher rate-*which is critical*.**

Moreover the "% Answered" and the "Answers ratio" hold, despite the increased rate of new Questions -which also means that contributions keep up with the incoming flow.

In light of the above, the "Avid users" metric, although still the most serious threat in my opinion, worries me less now than 30 days earlier. But that's most probably psychology, a framing effect -and as economists we should know better than falling victims to framing effects.

**So keep worrying -and keep up the pace.**

Comment: Yes, these look like better numbers. In my eyes, the main challenge is still keeping a good balance of expert-level material as a broader audience comes onto the site.

Comment: I've been meaning to drop by and give this community a couple of thoughts from the SE community team's perspective. Your commitment to tracking your progress has in of itself been a cool exercise. In any case, keep an eye out for a longer answer. :)

Comment: @Ana Eyes wide open.

Comment: Only one red criterium and even a green word! Best we've been so far!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SE Community Team, of which I'm a member, has been keeping an eye on things on Economics SE, so I thought sharing some observations from our side might be helpful.

### tl;dr Economics.SE is coming along nicely.

The whole way along, I've been impressed by the ownership you've all taken of this site. Members of this community have consistently shown that they care enough to post here in meta, raise questions, and reflect on your collective progress. Any site needs an engaged core of users to have any longevity. Seems you've got that covered. *As for some specifics...*

**Your rate of questions/day is strong.**

7 questions/day for a relatively new community is very healthy. Nicely done! A disclaimer: don't worry too much about activity dropping off due to the seasonal nature of this topic. It's okay. It's cyclical, its natural; just keep doing what you're doing and trust that it'll all bounce back. Quality is always most important.

**Economics.SE needs you to vote more.**

Voting activity has fluctuated, and I encourage you to make it a consistent habit. Please vote (up and down) more consistently and readily. Rep is the simplest, most powerful feedback mechanism available on an SE site. Use it!

**Band together to address unanswered questions?**

You have a sizable number of unanswered questions. Unanswered questions can hinder growth because when new users show up via search engine and don't find answers, they don't tend to stick around. One idea for tackling unanswered questions might be organizing an initiative to address a few of them per week. Rallying everyone around one goal might prove to be helpful.

### I believe Economics.SE is indeed picking up steam. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 5):

I was looking forward to this post for a few days now. I think however the key variable is the `300` visit, because that seems to be more stable. The `questions/day` is, iirc, a mean value over a few days, and could potentially change over the course of the next days.

Visits is key to keeping this up, and this time it seems not to be coming from a few super-popular layman questions, which speaks for its stability.

I'm generally positive, but one thing could get you worried: In a month or so, exams start, and then there's gonna be much less activity here from the undergraduates.

Comment: ...or much more, to solve last-minute scratch-heads in their study. Seasonality is to be expected, but indeed, what leaves doesn't necessarily come back, when the site is not yet "established". By the way, I've been meaning to applaud you for the questions you post in the main -they are exactly the sort of questions needed towards a "good balance of expert-level material" mentioned in @Ubiquitous answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there's increasing growth in the number of users, I think that is a positive sign.

I think what this site is suffering from, is generally a lack of users.

You could question how much *more* the existing users can do (eg. answering more questions, browsing more frequently), but I think what this site really needs is more users.

Comment: Your answer seems to have been cut off abruptly. Should we expect more?

Comment: he suddenly dropped out of being an 'engaged user'

Comment: Totes can't remember what I was writing here.