# 272 days in Beta - What's next?

Tags: discussion

As scheduled 3 months after the [previous report](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1344/180-1-days-in-beta-is-it-acquiring-a-life-of-its-own)...

[image]

Nothing much to comment really, the dive in questions is only natural for this period of the year, while visits (I remind that it is a *median*, not an average) remain steady, while participation and usage grows.

Just one thing : it *drives me really crazy* that for all this period of nine months, *every single time* I measured average daily rate of new subscriptions, they were always around $7-8$/day. I don't remember seeing such steady metric in any new venture in my whole life. And yes, it is not a steady growth *rate*, but it is steady in levels, which points towards [a CARA rather than a CRRA](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/why-is-crra-utility-often-used-in-macroeconomics-dsge-model/1814#1814) framework.

I will return for the tables, where I will show quarterly data from now on.

Comment: Although it may not be surprising that there are fewer questions at this time of year, the reduction to 3.6 per day is from a previous quarter's level of 5.7 per day that was itself well below the suggested healthy level of 10 per day.  Are we still perhaps at a stage where it would be helpful to post questions that we consider would provide and/or stimulate good content - even if they are not questions we would have posted simply to obtain answers?

Comment: @AdamBailey Yes, this is a good policy. As for the dive in questions and the distance to 10/day, if the site bounces back come Autumn to 5-6 questions/day, then I would not necessarily expect to see a quick rise to 10/day. In any case, the beta performance has been very good so far, compared to other sites that started off approximately around the same time as economics.se

Answer (score 3):

Taken from Adam Bailey's comment:

> Are we still perhaps at a stage where it would be helpful to post questions that we consider would provide and/or stimulate good content - even if they are not questions we would have posted simply to obtain answers?

This is a good strategy *provided* you only ask and answer questions which you'd be happy to have on the site anyway, even if you were at 10+ questions/day and had no need for extra activity. There's also no way for that to be regulated externally. You, the community, will need need determine what those standards are for yourself and decide to work together to adhere to the,.

It's also important to note that while you certainly *can* look at activity, [quality is what all sites network-wide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) are really on the hook for. 3.6 questions/day is no problem as far as the Community Team is concerned. One of these days, we'll even get around to changing those Area51 stats so they don't look so scary. :)